Girl hits herself on a washbasin so her boyfriend will beat up another boy
There's this movie where a boy watches lot of porn and stuff. One day he finds out there's a girl in his school or college, who is also on the website. He chats with her. They decide to meet. He goes to her house to have sex. But he comes to his senses and runs away from her house without having sex. Then she hits herself on a washbasin. Her boyfriend comes and hits this boy as she blames the injury on him. 
Does someone recognize this movie?

Sounds like Cyber Seduction: His Secret Life  (2005) with Kelly Lynch and Lyndsy Fonseca. From Wiki:

Justin Petersen is a popular 16-year-old high school student and a successful swimmer with a steady girlfriend, Amy. [...] Justin is introduced to internet pornography when a friend sends him a link to a softcore featuring Monica, a fellow student who has a crush on him. [...] Justin becomes closer to Monica and increasingly ignores Amy.
However, when Monica tries to seduce him, Justin hesitates, and an angry Monica kicks him out of her house. Monica throws a physical tantrum alone after feeling rejected by Justin and bangs her own head [on a sink], causing it to bleed. [...] Monica is seen in a restaurant with noticeable face injuries, and it is presumed she told others that Justin was responsible for them. The schoolmates beat Justin up on the street, disturbed by his reputation and the alleged incident with Monica.

Here's the trailer:




Oh god I have seen this.  It was so over the top.
